# See number of logs in /var/log?

Tags: logs, syslog

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how many logs entries are being generated by my software each day (AlienVault OSSIM, if it helps to know). Is there some command I can use to see how many logs entries are in `/var/log` total (so the entire directory) **OR** some command to see how many logs entries are in `/var/log/messages`?
**My goal is just to find out how many logs entries are being generated each day.**

Preferably, both commands (if they exist) would be useful.

Comment: Does the software use `systemd`? Is counting logs just counting lines?

Comment: @FelixJN So I do see `systemd` under `/etc`, so looks like it uses `systemd`? Does that mean each log is a line?

Comment: Many challenges to consider...  How precise are you trying to be (e.g., would a `wc -l` against a day's logrotate be sufficient!?)?  Are all your applications/processes following logging best practices (e.g., single line entries!?)?  Are all your /var/log files going through `syslog` (e.g., for standardized date prefixes) or are they all following a standardized date format?  Tools that might/would be useful: `find`, `wc`, `cat`/`zcat`/`bzcat`, `grep` et al, `awk` or `sed`, `date`, etc..

Comment: If you're looking for rough estimate, and all your logs are rolled daily by logrotate, consider `wc -l`ing the same rolled set (e.g., all files ending in `.0`).  If you're looking for something more precise, consider using `find` in conjunction with a script to extract dates/times, attempt to combine multi-line entries, etc., and count entries with that.